# Would somebody describe the exact position of this man in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation

> "When they arrived, the body was lying on the sand with its head resting on the seawall, and with its feet crossed and pointing directly to the sea".

If his head was resting on the seawall then how come his feet were crossed and pointing directly to the sea?

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. [Images of seawall](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=image+of+seawall+&oq=image+of+seawall+&gs_l=hp.3...150141.155712.1.156080.10.10.0.0.0.0.89.630.10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.j2PQtSeAvRY&pbx=1&biw=1250&bih=853&cad=cbv&sei=zsVJUa69GKiw0AW2_oCQBg) are easy to Google, which should make the meaning clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an image of a seawall:

[image]

So the body (seems like a dead body from the context) was resting it's head on the seawall and was facing towards the sea with it's legs crossed.

Although I am not a good painter, but I will try to elaborate the position through my own picture.

[image: my own picture]

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawall):

> A seawall (also written as sea wall) is a form of coastal defense
>   constructed where the sea, and associated coastal processes, impact
>   directly upon the landforms of the coast.

So it's not a wall 'of' sea, but a wall 'to stop' the sea.  It sits further up the beach than the shore line to prevent the shore (dunes etc) from being washed away *into* the sea.